# Stm32 Log Messages

Tags: c, embedded, stm32cubeide

good day, stm32 nucleo board I want to write informative Log messages using.
For example, I want to display the message that the program has started by using the Log("Program started") function when the program starts during this period, or I want to give the error message to the screen by using the Log("Program Failed') function when the program fails.
I using C programming langue and stm32cubeide & Nucleo f207zg board thanks in advance for your help

Thanks I solved the problem

Comment: I new in this platform if i do ant mistake please forgive me

Comment: Actually, I want to write a general Log() function and indicate the cases where the code fails or works as a message using this function.

Comment: "_display the message_" - on what? "_error message to the screen_" - what screen?  The board you describe does not have a screen. What your board does have, is hardware debug support (via an on-board ST-Link debugger); in many cases using a debugger is preferable to _"printf debugging"_.

Comment: What do you want this log function to do that makes it not simply a "print" function - you need to specify.  For example it might display file/function/linenumber information.  It might also have behaviour requirements such as being safe to call in an ISR, or being "non-blocking" so that the output does not interfere with the real-time behaviour of the code.  There is too much unstated/unspecified in these requirement to help you to be honest.

Comment: Rather than adding requirements or clarifications in comments, update the question with that information.

Comment: It really depends on the application tbh, sometimes printing on a serial is quicker and easier than using the debugger. Also because stopping the execution of the code breaks the interrupts or any timed function on the micro, so if the serial printing is not enormous is a fine way of debugging. I also used LED debugging sometimes, lighting an LED if the program was taking a branch or not.

Comment: @Fra93 : Well I was clear to not be too emphatic - "_in many cases_".  Often novices do not even realise the debug capability they have available or how to use it.  Debugging with `printf()` necessarily means debugging modified code - such modifications can change the behaviour and timing of the code.  Also you have to know that your debug code has no errors; that is not a given since by definition you have written buggy code.  SO is full of questions about bugs that turn out to be erroneous observations of incorrectly instrumented code.

Comment: I take your point about real-time code and breakpoints, but in STM32 at least the peripheral clocks can be stopped on a breakpoint.  External input an events can of course overrun.  Since it is possible to observe memory changes without hitting a breakpoint using watchpoints, it is possible to debug real-time events in a debugger.  Keil's debugger for example included a "logic analyser" function that can monitor variables or registers in real time at machine cycle resolution  - better than an LED.

Comment: Maybe an internal trace buffer wih `ModuleId, ApiId, ErrorCode, Timestamp` is usually enough, plus a `Trace(ModuleId, ApiId, ErrorCode)` function, which you call from the functions with the above encoded data. The trace module could even have additional feature to stop on a specific error, and in the debugger, you even have the stack trace available (looking back in the stack trace, who called the trace function, together with the arguments/local data causing the problem. And you would just log errors. No message is a good message.

Answer (score 1):

Given that:

- You know what the UART/USART peripheral is
- You connected the right pins to a serial interface
- You connected the other end of the interface (for instance an FTDI chip) to your computer

You can implement the logging  with `printf` as you would do in C. Why? Because printf already takes care for you the formatting of the strings, which no one wants to reimplement, and then you redirect the printf output to the UART peripheral that handles low level serial protocol.

Following [this guide](https://forum.digikey.com/t/easily-use-printf-on-stm32/20157) the steps are easy enough:

> Add #include <stdio.h> to the Includes section at the top of the main.c

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

> Copy and paste the following code into the main.c file before the main() function but after the UART handle declaration

Note that you need to replace the question mark with the actual UART handle declaration, for instance `huart1`

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_putchar(int ch)
#else
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
#endif

PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart?, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  return ch;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to get data from usart3 and I have placed the printf function as you said, but what I'm trying to do is to make a Log() function that will output the x function to the screen when the x function is running.How can I create this function and where do I need to create it?

Comment: You need to be more clear when you say "will output the x function to the screen when the x function" because withouth an example it does not mean much. Why can't you put the Log function in several places inside your "x" function so that it prints the state in which the function is?

Comment: I want to write a function that will write "function worked" to the screen while the function is running.

Comment: Then use the printf to write it, what is the problem here?

Comment: For example, when the Init function runs, I want it to write to the screen that the Init function is running now.

Comment: Put a printf inside the function, no? Why is this not a solution?

Comment: The Nucleo board described already has serial I/O via its USB debug/programming interface no need for additional hardware.

Comment: @Clifford are you replying to me? The STM32 still has several UART interfaces, you need to use the one connected to the FTDI on the board, otherwise you'll write on some unconnnected pins. I meant that. The USB/Debugging you mentioned is the STlink, which indeed is the debugger/programmer but AFAIK you can't access it easily from a basic "main.c" application. It works as a master for start/stop/readmemory.

Comment: Yes - it is a comment on the answer.  There is no FTDI on the board, it is implemented using an STM32F103C microcontroller providing mass storage (for drag-and-drop flash programming), Virtual COM port, and OCD debug port.  My point is that the OP stated what board he was using and it already has the hardware that you were telling him he needed to implement.  He also states he wants to _display_ messages on a _screen_ without clarification about what that means - if  he in fact means to output serial data for a PC to display, then he needs to specify that perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Fra93, you need to implement UART/USART protocol communication and print stuff to there. I'm writing this reply, because I'm getting a feeling you have some basic experience writing desktop applications, but not embedded, so I will clarify a few points.

**There is no console to print to. There are no logs. They simply don't exist.** At all. Not in a desktop app development sense.

What's usually done is that one of the UARTs of the MCU is used to print characters to the ST-Link, which converts it to USB (alternatively, can be FTDI IC, CP2102 or other USB-UART bridges/converters). So then your MCU will send out characters over UART, and the USB-UART converter will display them in a COM port terminal (programs like PuTTy)

If you start with empty project and no external libraries used, you will need 3 dozen lines of code alone just to be able to print stuff. Initially, you have nothing. You have to initialize UART, configure it, then implement how it handles characters, numbers. You need to literally write a basic UART driver. And you can call printing function whatever you want. You can call it Log("hello world"), you can call it Whisper("hi there"). Because you will actually create this function. You're the boss.

Now, given you are not very familiar with all of this, it may sound like a difficult task. And it most certainly is. Writing a driver from scratch on your day 1 is not a thing you want to do (unless you're into that kind of stuff on day 1).

I would strongly advise you to get some library, such as HAL by STMicroelectronics, and familiarize yourself with what it can do - including how to print stuff with UART. Internet is flooded with articles and videos of how to use UART with HAL, it's literally one of the first things to be implemented. Specifically for the reason, that it works like logs and simplifies further development/learning.

**So, in order to get "logs" working, I would do the following:**

1. Get HAL for your specific MCU
2. Familiarize yourself with UART - basic stuff about what it is and how it works. No need to be an expert, just learn what it is.
3. Familiarize yourself with how to use UART with HAL
4. From the schematic of the PCB of your nucleo board, find out which UART of the MCU is connected to ST-Link (I checked the schematic: it's USART3)
5. Get serial port (COM) terminal program for your computer
6. Use HAL to initialize USART3 and print to USART3. Whatever you print there will be visible in the terminal. Yes, you will not see anything in the IDE. You need a separate program to display what you receive via USB COM port.

In the end, your print function will be the one proposed by Fra93. HAL_UART_Transmit is the most basic HAL function to send stuff via UART. If you're very picky about using "Log" as a function you call to print via UART, you can always wrap HAL_UART_Transmit into your own function called Log.